# Looping and text extracting with iMacro

Tags: imacros

I am trying to extract some text from the web with iMacro.

I use Chrome and Firefox and latest iMacros for these. I have looked the ways from google and tried to put it to loop, but somehow it's not working still. I can extract tagging them one by one with names and all the things but would like to set it to loop.

I tried to use

```
SET !Loop 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

also

```
TAG POS={{!Loop}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

but it's not working

My initial code is here, I appreciate a lot if someone could point out where to put the loop, so it works how to make it work:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://angel.co/blogging-platforms
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

'Extract 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:MessageParty EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Chat<SP>with<SP>People<SP>Near<SP>You 
EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV 
ATTR=TXT:New<SP>York<SP>City<SP>·<SP>Location<SP>Based<SP>Services 
EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Apr<SP>’12 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:23 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=32 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT: EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=33 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT: EXTRACT=TXT

'Save as
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=platforms.csv
```

Also how I can set it so that it saves all extracted data on the different rows. When I tried it with tagging 5 and running the macro then it saved all on the same line to different columns.

If I remove ATTR=**TXT:MessageParty** and replace it with the wildcard **ATTR=*** then it doesn't work either.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the code like suggested below?

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:name EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:blurb EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:tags EXTRACT=TXT
' and so on '
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=platforms.csv
```

---

I go manually to https://angel.co/blogging-platforms and run the macro above.

It gives me the 'platforms.csv' file like this:

```
"Squarespace","Build it beautiful.","New York City · Blogging Platforms"
"MessageParty","Chat with People Near You","New York City · Location Based Services"
"Medium","We make Medium: A Publishing Platform.","San Francisco · Blogging Platforms"
"Svbtle","A new kind of publishing platform.","San Francisco · Blogging Platforms"
"Posterous","","San Francisco · Networking"
"Six Apart","","Tokyo · Blogging Platforms"
"Automattic","","San Francisco · Forums"
```

etc.

(I use 'iMacros for Firefox' v.**8.9.7**)

---

Adding the code for the 'Joined' and 'Followers' fields:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:name EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:blurb EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:tags EXTRACT=TXT

TAG POS=R1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:"value" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:"value" EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=platforms.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Shugar. It works for the first one and loops it as many times needed, but is not going to loop over others, what was the initial meaning. Do you know why?

Comment: Do you play this macro in **loop mode** (by pressing the 'Play (Loop)' button)?

Comment: Yes Shugar, I play it by pressing the 'Play (Loop)' button. But it loops only the first one based on the number what I put to the loop window.  I am just getting lot repetitions from the first row: Squarespace, Build it beautiful, New York City · Blogging Platforms like. It's not going to the second one, (MessageParty, Chat with People Near You, New York City · Location Based Services) third one etc. on the page.

I am using Firefox and tried also with Chrome.

Comment: See my update. I have no idea what is the reason of the problem described by you. Anyway try to downgrade 'iMacros for Firefox' to v. **8.9.7**, because v.9.0.3 is known as full of bugs.

Comment: Thank you, Shugar. It works now, but I am not able to add Joined and Followers field to the code. I am not finding the right tag. 

If i use ATTR:class:value "TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:value EXTRACT=TXT" then it takes value from the beginning of the page and then from that column and so on

 Do you know how I can find it or I can do it? Can you help me here?

Comment: It's pretty easy with the help of Relative Positioning. Try the update.